# Hiding a drupal block on particular page

Tags: blocks

I am trying to hide a Drupal block on a View page.

The View url is http://localhost/alphabetical

And name of the block is family tree. So I went to `Structure ->Block ->Configure(for Family tree)`
and added `/alphabetical` to Show block on specific pages(with Radio button All pages except those listed)
But it didn't work.
Then I cleared all the caches.Still it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the block configuration page, in the *Pages* tab select *All pages except those listed*; in the text area below, write *alphabetical*. As the example shown in the description for the text area, you don't need the slash at the beginning of the path.

[image: screenshot]